# Time of logs of cloud front

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I try to collect cloud-front-logs from S3's bucket and put those it into database.
Date time of logs in these files are really problem.
Is it logged in the time of Standard Time? or the time of x-edge-location?
If I want to fix this to Japan's Standard Time should I calculate by x-edge-location?

I have one more question.
Do logs delay when those written on S3 bucket??
If I observe my s3bucket by using "s3cmd ls s3://mys3bucket/".
Log's count changes within 2 hours.

Answer (score 3):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=30346

> The date and hour are specified according to the GMT time zone.
>   I found this answer.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html

> CloudFront saves log files within 24 hours after receiving the corresponding requests.